# Python: How to get local maxima values from 1D-array or list

Tags: python, numpy, local

I am pretty new in Python and I have a problem which I could not solve with found answers... hopefully someone can help:
I need to get a list of all local maxima of a data-set which is imported from a csv-file.
Values range from 0 to 0.5 or so.

I just need to get a list of those local maxima of one data row ("Werte", array or "N", list) to do statistics on them.

This is what I have got:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import *

N = []   

file = open('C:/Auswertung/PEE/PEE_L_1_O_130702-1.1.csv', 'r') 
Probe = file.readline()         # lese Inhalt zeilenweise in Listen
Header = file.readline()
data = file.readlines()

for row in data:
    columns = row.split(";")       # Trenne Zeilen bei ';' 
    N.append(float(columns[1]))

Werte = np.array([N])

# one try here: only gives me a set of 1s...    
c = (diff(sign(diff(Werte))) < 0).nonzero()[0] + 1 # local max
print(c)
```

is there anyone who could help me find the right way to do it?
Thank you a lot!

Comment: If you have [2 4 4 4 0], should 4 be considered as the max?

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for `argrelmax`, from `scipy.signal`. It gives you the indices of the relative maxima of a 1d array.

```
from scipy.signal import argrelmax
t=linspace(-4,40,1000)
y=sin(t)
argrelmax(y)[0]
```

with result

```
[126 269 412 554 697 840 982]
```

to get the values, use

```
y[argrelmax(y)[0]]
```

EDIT:

notice that it does not count local maxima at the extreme of your domain.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. The only extra thing you need is to slice the Werke array. 
but I think, finding the local max can be simplified to:

```
 werte[1:-1][(diff(werte)[:-1]>0)*(diff(werte)[1:]<0)]
```

@Jamine was quite right, `&` instead of `*` makes it reads better.

Comment: Since you are combining boolean arrays, I'd say it is more revealing of your intention to `&` your two arrays, not to `*` them.